# couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsi.so" not found:

Tags: react-native, performance, android-studio, react-native-hermes

I try to enable hermes engine on RN- ~0.63.3 version
after running the app and making apk , unfortunately apk app got crashed and error showing in logcat
#warning
*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjsi.so" not found:*
#Error
*couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsi.so" not found*

RN- ~0.63.3 following official docs how to enable hermes in existing RN app

expecting app should run on enabling hermes

Comment: Hermes engine is a bit tricky to run on older versions of react-native, if ever you can't find a solution, I would suggest you upgrade the version of react-native. Hermes works much better from versions 0.68 and above.

Answer (score -1):

**work for me**

```
in build.gradle 

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false, <<<< Changed from true to false. App is bundling fine again
    ...
]
```